# Вместо последнего элемента массива выводится мусор

Tags: c++, массивы, вывод, файловый-ввод-вывод

Нужно считать из первого текстового файла 25 элементов действительного типа,
расположенных в столбик, и занести их в двумерный массив 5х5 в виде матрицы во второй текстовый файл. Для каждого столбца массива найти и распечатать также во второй текстовый файл нулевые элементы и их количество. Застопорился том моменте когда вместо последнего элемента массива выводится мусор, не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    int amount = 0;
    fin.open("MyFile.txt");
    const int ROW = 5;
    const int COLUMN = 5;
    int arr[ROW][COLUMN];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            fin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    string path = "MyFile2.txt";
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
            fout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
        fout << endl;
    }
    fout << "amount of elements= " << amount;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подозрительный последний элемент массива мы наконец-то увидели. Осталось увидеть содержимое текстового файла.

Comment: Вы уверены что у Вас там 25 строк в текстовом файле, я проверил код он полностью рабочий если  не считать этого пункта `Для каждого столбца массива найти и распечатать также во второй текстовый файл нулевые элементы и их количество.` - хотя возможно тут я ошибаюсь, но я понимаю должно быть примерно так  `0 1`  (первый столбец) `0 0 0 3` второй столбец и т.д.

Comment: так и есть 24 числа вместо 25

Comment: Да, заметил) Если бы не вы я там наверное ещё часа два колупался. Спасибо

Comment: А вас об этом спрашивали еще в первый раз, когда этот вопрос задавался вами под другим аккаунтом. Вспомните — я тогда еще написал, что эта задача решается без массивов, они тут просто ни к чему.

Answer (score 2):

Не без определенного раздражения напомню, что всё желательно приводить текстом — ну вот кому интересно набирать ваш файл с данными?, и что крайне желательно прислушиваться к тому, что говорят — раз уж вы ищете помощь. Еще когда этот вопрос был задан вами под другим ником, вам указывали, что проблема скорее всего во входных данных. Вы и сейчас их не сразу привели...

Ну, а второе — для решения этого вопроса не нужны никакие массивы или несколько циклов. Проверку на то, что файлы открылись, делать не стал, так как и у вас ее нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("MyFile.txt");
    ofstream fout("MyFile2.txt");
    const int ROW = 5;
    const int COLUMN = 5;
    int zeros = 0;
    for(int i = 0, j = 0, n; i < ROW*COLUMN; i++)
    {
        if (fin >> n) // if - чтобы сразу увидеть, если ошибка
                      // Можете посмотреть, как отработает на ваших данных
        {
            if (n == 0) ++zeros;
            cout << n << "\t";  fout << n << "\t";
            if (++j % COLUMN == 0) { fout << "\n"; cout << "\n"; }
        }
    }
    fout << "\n\nZeros: " << zeros << "\n";
}
```

Вопрос с выводом во второй файл (в тот же? Еще один?) нулевых элементов (они и так выведены, среди прочих. Или *только* их? в каком виде?) оставляю открытым из-за отсутствия внятной формулировки.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда встречаю подобные задачи, всегда задумываюсь почему бы не делать все за один проход, тут конечно понадобится еще один цикл для вывода сумм, но можно сэкономить на двумерном массиве:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int ROW = 5;
    const int COLUMN = 5;
    string path = "MyFile2.txt";
    int value;
    int amount[COLUMN]{0};
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    fin.open("MyFile.txt");
    fout.open(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            fin >> value;
            fout << setw(3) << (value == 0 ? '0' : ' ');
            if (value == 0) {
                amount[j]++;
            }
        }
        fout << endl;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++){
        fout << setw(3) << amount[j];
    }
    fout << endl;    
    fout.close();
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод (как я его понимаю):

> Для каждого столбца массива найти и распечатать также во второй
> текстовый файл нулевые элементы и их количество

```
        0  0   
     0         
               
  0  0         
     0         
  1  3  1  1  0
```